# alpha bibliography issue with accents

Tags: bibtex, classicthesis

I'm using `classicthesis`. In my `bibliography.bib` file I have an author like this:

```
@Book{m,
 author = {M\'endez, blah blah},
 title = {Title 1},
 publisher = {aaa},
 year = {2006}
 }

@Book{m2,
 author = {M\'endez, blah blah},
 title = {Title 2},
 publisher = {aaa},
 year = {2006}
 }
```

I am using the `alpha` bibliography style. This style, instead of displaying [Me06a] or [Mé06a] and [Me06b] or [Mé06b], displays [Mó6a] and [Mó6b]. I've tried with

```
author = {M{\'e}ndez, blah blah}
```

or

```
author = {{M\'e}ndez, blah blah},
```

but that didn't really help. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this minimal file

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{m,
 author = {M{\'e}ndez, blah blah},
 title = {Title 1},
 publisher = {aaa},
 year = {2006}
 }

@Book{m2,
 author = {M{\'e}ndez, blah blah},
 title = {Title 2},
 publisher = {aaa},
 year = {2010}
 }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output

[image]

The `filecontents*` environment is just to have a self-contained file.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It doesn't matter; the mark is still "Mén06", because the font uses "oldstyle numbers".